# Process for Web Automation Testing

Tags: browser-automation

Can I get details about what process or steps should be taken for web automation testing?

I am currently using Selenium IDE & eclipse.from testing. I am focusing on open source tools for web testing. Please provide me what basic steps or points should be considered during web automation testing. The project I am working follows agile process. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How much coding experience do you have? Do you know OOP? Have you worked with Selenium before, or another UI testing framework?

Comment: Hi Ethel,I have just started with web Automation Testing(beginner),I am good in java and OOPs concepts.Selenium is the first tool which i am working on.

Comment: Depending on how early in the cycle you are, automation may be a waste of time, especially if design/implementations are changing with high velocity . . . you'll end up spending more time maintaining tests than doing actual testing . . .

Comment: Automate website testing quickly and easily with TestComplete. The UI testing tool comes with full support for popular browsers and intelligent object recognition across major technologies. TestComplete is a web testing automation tool that integrates with build servers, source control systems, and defect management tools so you can run automated tests around the clock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Appium and selenium do well for functionality testing,  for load testing jmeter works pretty well.

Automated testing works a lot like any structured testing.   Follow test cases,  determine if pass or fail.

In many cases unit testing is important as it can prevent bugs early in development .

Answer (score 0):

According to me for functionality automation testing Selenium web driver is best tool. It require basic knowledge of Java programming.

Selenium also supports other programming languages like ruby , python and some others. So if you have command over any one from selenium supported languages then would be easy to pick up for automation.

Some helpful links for selenium is given below :

http://docs.seleniumhq.org/projects/webdriver/

http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp

http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/

Answer (score 0):

In automation testing open source tools are available.
The best Tool for automation is **Appium**.
Appium is a automation tool for web and native apps i.e android and Ios platforms also supports.

below link is for appium,how to use appium and its documentation.

http://appium.io/documentation.html

Answer (score 0):

Web automation testing is a critical process that needs the right understanding of the testing techniques, tools, and methodology. Since I am associated with a quality assurance and software testing company providing web automation testing services, here are a few good reads from our blog section that can make things easy for you: [Web Automation Tips and Best Practices](https://www.bugraptors.com/blog/web-test-automation-tips-and-best-practices)